# Make img from ext4, dtb and uboot.bin

Tags: yocto, u-boot

I have recently used yocto to compile a custom OS and it resulted in the constituent parts of the ext4 file structure, the hardware dtb and the uboot image.

The device I am trying to replace the firmware on is android based and has its own windows based application to replace the firmware. The software needs a singular img file.

Is it possible to compile one from the 3 files listed above?

I have been looking at mkimage but to no joy. I don't know how to use the -d script possibly. Yocto produces a file that looks like it would work with -d argument but doesn't seem to.

I come from OpenWRT where it produced a single bin image which could be mtd'd (the verb to use mtd).

Thoughts?

My build configuration is:

```
Build Configuration:

BB_VERSION           = "1.37.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "aarch64-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "nexbox-a95x-s905x"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "2.5"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "aarch64"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta
meta-poky
meta-yocto-bsp       = "sumo:b369e613a1d3af6439905724031aa2b75423aeee"
meta-meson           = "sumo:9a060d8cb106fd86ed7ac93b66675a639bfc6045"
meta-oe
meta-python
meta-networking      = "master:bb57bac845f3cd1634862fa9868bc8e294ba74a9"
meta-openwrt         = "master:3f94c4f5aa965aa5d65419d6691b40a3870e84a8"
```

No other changes made to config files.

Resultant files are:

```
aml_autoscript
amlogic-image-headless-sd-nexbox-a95x-s905x-20180608105022.testdata.json
amlogic-image-headless-sd-nexbox-a95x-s905x-20180609220030.rootfs.ext4
amlogic-image-headless-sd-nexbox-a95x-s905x-20180609220030.rootfs.manifest
amlogic-image-headless-sd-nexbox-a95x-s905x-20180609220030.rootfs.tar.bz2
amlogic-image-headless-sd-nexbox-a95x-s905x-20180609220030.testdata.json
amlogic-image-headless-sd-nexbox-a95x-s905x.ext4
amlogic-image-headless-sd-nexbox-a95x-s905x.manifest
amlogic-image-headless-sd-nexbox-a95x-s905x.tar.bz2
amlogic-image-headless-sd-nexbox-a95x-s905x.testdata.json
Image--4.16.5+git0+e5ce9f6879-r0-meson-gxl-s905x-nexbox-a95x-20180608105022.dtb
Image-meson-gxl-s905x-nexbox-a95x.dtb
meson-gxl-s905x-nexbox-a95x.dtb
modules--4.16.5+git0+e5ce9f6879-r0-nexbox-a95x-s905x-20180608105022.tgz
modules-nexbox-a95x-s905x.tgz
uImage
uImage--4.16.5+git0+e5ce9f6879-r0-nexbox-a95x-s905x-20180608105022.bin
uImage-nexbox-a95x-s905x.bin
```

Comment: Which type of image you need depends very much on the architecture you are on. For which CPU and which device do you try to pack U-Boot?  For many devices supported by OpenWRT there is no support in mainline U-Boot. Did OpenWRT really overwrite the existing U-Boot?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [skales-tools](https://packages.debian.org/sid/skales)

1. dtbTool -o dt.img arch/arm/dts/
2. mkbootimg --kernel=uboot.bin --dt=dt.img --cmdline="" --pagesize 2048 --base  --output=u-boot.img --ramdisk=

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the img you want to generate is using mkimage tool? mkimage is used to make u-boot image. What you are looking for is probably the [genimage](https://github.com/pengutronix/genimage) tool to combine all the generated output in one single image.